# Creating methods within a class method in Typescript - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-services

In Angular 2 I'm using bootbox.js to create dialogs (alerts, confirmations). I'm trying to create a dialog service, but I'm not sure how to write the code in Typescript is such a way that would allow me to use my service methods the way I'm hoping to.

**How I want to use my service:**

```
export class SomeComponent {

  constructor(private _dialog: DialogService){}

  showConfirm() {
    _dialog.confirm()
      .title('Some title')
      .message('Some message')
      .okBtn('Sounds Good')
      .cancelBtn('No way!')
      .confirm(() => {})
      .cancel(() => {})
  }

showAlert() {
        _dialog.alert()
          .title('Some title')
          .message('Some message')
          .okBtn('Sounds Good')
          .callback(() => {})
      }
```

**My service as it currently:**

```
export class DialogService {

confirm() {
    bootbox.dialog({
      title: title,
      message: message,
      buttons: {
        cancel: {
          label: cancelBtn,
          className: 'btn-inverse btn-inverse-primary',
          callback: () => cancel()
        },
        okay: {
          label: okBtn,
          className: 'btn-inverse btn-inverse-primary',
          callback: () => confirm()
        }
      }
    })
  }

 alert() {
    bootbox.dialog({
      title: title,
      message: message,
      buttons: {
        okay: {
          label: okBtn,
          className: 'btn-inverse btn-inverse-primary',
          callback: () => callback()
        }
      }
    })
  }

}
```

Obviously I would rather pass in the title, message, etc. from the component that's using my service, but I'm just not sure how to write the service to allow the usage to be done the way I would to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then you're looking for [the builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Here's an implementation based on your code:

```
class DialogService {
    private _title: string;
    private _message: string;
    private _okBtn: string;
    private _cancelBtn: string;
    private _confirm: string;
    private _cancel: string;

    constructor() {}

    public title(value: string): DialogService {
        this._title = value;
        return this;
    }

    public message(value: string): DialogService {
        this._message = value;
        return this;
    }

    public okBtn(value: string): DialogService {
        this._okBtn = value;
        return this;
    }

    public cancelBtn(value: string): DialogService {
        this._cancelBtn = value;
        return this;
    }

    public confirm(value: () => {}): DialogService {
        this._confirm = value;
        return this;
    }

    public cancel(value: () => {}): DialogService {
        this._cancel = value;
        return this;
    }

    public show(): void {
        bootbox.dialog({
            title: this._title,
            message: this._message,
            buttons: {
                cancel: {
                    label: this._cancelBtn,
                    className: 'btn-inverse btn-inverse-primary',
                    callback: this._cancel
                },
                okay: {
                    label: okBtn,
                    className: 'btn-inverse btn-inverse-primary',
                    callback: this._confirm
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then:

```
new DialogService()
    .title('Some title')
    .message('Some message')
    .okBtn('Sounds Good')
    .cancelBtn('No way!')
    .confirm(() => {})
    .cancel(() => {})
    .show();
```

---

#### Edit

I saw your changed question after posting this edit, so I'm re-editing it:

```
interface ButtonData {
    label: string;
    className: string;
    callback: () => void;
}

class DialogService {
    private static BUTTON_CLASS_NAME = "btn-inverse btn-inverse-primary";

    private _title: string;
    private _message: string;
    private _okay: ButtonData;
    private _cancel: ButtonData;

    constructor() {}

    public title(value: string): DialogService {
        this._title = value;
        return this;
    }

    public message(value: string): DialogService {
        this._message = value;
        return this;
    }

    public okay(label: string, callback?: () => void): DialogService {
        this._okay = {
            label: label,
            className: DialogService.BUTTON_CLASS_NAME,
            callback: callback || function() {}
        };

        return this;
    }

    public cancel(label: string, callback?: () => void): DialogService {
        this._cancel = {
            label: label,
            className: DialogService.BUTTON_CLASS_NAME,
            callback: callback || function() {}
        };

        return this;
    }

    public alert(): void {
        bootbox.dialog({
            title: this._title,
            message: this._message,
            buttons: {
                okay: this.okay
            }
        });
    }

    public confirm(): void {
        bootbox.dialog({
            title: this._title,
            message: this._message,
            buttons: {
                cancel: this._cancel,
                okay: this.okay
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**older edit**

I'm still not sure what exactly you're looking for, I changed things a bit and made sure that there are `confirm` and `alert` methods, but I'm not sure what they are supposed to do...
The `confirm` uses the `bootbox.dialog` your code has, but I had no idea what to do with the `alert` so I invented the `bootbox.alert` function.
It's probably wrong and you'll need to implement that yourself...

```
interface ButtonData {
    label: string;
    className: string;
    callback: () => void;
}

interface ServiceData {
    title: string;
    message: string;
    buttons: {
        cancel: ButtonData,
        okay: ButtonData
    };
}

class DialogService {
    private static BUTTON_CLASS_NAME = "btn-inverse btn-inverse-primary";
    private data: ServiceData

    constructor() {
        this.data = <ServiceData> {
            buttons: {
                cancel: <ButtonData> {},
                okay: <ButtonData> {}
            }
        };
    }

    public title(value: string): DialogService {
        this.data.title = value;
        return this;
    }

    public message(value: string): DialogService {
        this.data.message = value;
        return this;
    }

    public okay(label: string, callback?: () => void): DialogService {
        this.data.buttons.okay = {
            label: label,
            className: DialogService.BUTTON_CLASS_NAME,
            callback: callback || function() {}
        }

        return this;
    }

    public cancel(label: string, callback?: () => void): DialogService {
        this.data.buttons.cancel = {
            label: label,
            className: DialogService.BUTTON_CLASS_NAME,
            callback: callback || function() {}
        }

        return this;
    }

    public confirm(): void {
        bootbox.dialog(this.data);
    }

    public alert(): void {
        bootbox.alert(this.data);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is almost what I was thinking. There is going to be two methods though; alert and confirm

Comment: I wasn't planning for my code to fit exactly, just to give you an example of how to implement the builder pattern in your case. You should modify it to answer your exact needs.

Comment: I don't understand how this would work if there's two methods? I'm a noob.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want to do. What is the difference between `alert` and `confirm`? in your `confirm` function you're calling `bootbox.dialog`, what will `alert` do? Also in your code inside the `confirm` function you call the same function in the ok button callback, is it meant to be recursive?

Comment: With one, I want to show an alert, and the other I want to show a confirm...so we will have a `_dialog.alert()` and a `_dialog.confirm()` with their own sets of methods. I was just showing confirm up top to keep things simple.

Comment: Check my revised answer, if it still doesn't fit your needs then please edit *your* question with more information

Comment: Thanks. I've edit my question to hopefully make more sense. Essentially I'm trying to create a dialog service similar to https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog but using bootbox.js instead in Angular 2. I liked how the usage of $mdDialog was easy...just chaining together methods.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like

```
export class DialogService {

public title: string;
public messafe: string;
.....  // all other properties

confirm() {
    bootbox.dialog({
      title: title,
      message: message,
      buttons: {
        cancel: {
          label: cancelBtn,
          className: 'btn-inverse btn-inverse-primary',
          callback: () => cancel()
        },
        okay: {
          label: okBtn,
          className: 'btn-inverse btn-inverse-primary',
          callback: () => confirm()
        }
      }
    })
  }

}
```

and then, in the component that uses the DialogService

```
export class SomeComponent {

  constructor(private _dialog: DialogService){}

  this._dialog.title = 'some title';
  this._dialog.message = 'some message';
  // the rest of the stuff

  this._dialog.showConfirm();

}
```

I hope I heve understood your point and that this helps